# Normalize data columns to compare answer of a survey with different ranges in r

Tags: r, range, evaluation, survey, normalize

I am very new to evaluating surveys. I conducted a survey with different scenarios (each scenario included a different tool) but the questions were the same for each scenario. the max of correct answers differs from each scenario (in scenario 1, the max answer is 8, in scenario 2 the max answer is 4 while in scenario 3 the max answer is 9). now i would like to compare the results of each scenario in a normalized boxplot. how can i include the best possible answer, eg. 8 in scenario 1, if none of the participants reach 8?

I would like to normalize the data for each column under consideration of the best possible answer. I though of adding the correct solution as entry in the dataset but this would skew the results as more "participants" would have taken part in the survey.

E.g. my data looks like this:

```
show(set1)
Part.  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    9
[2,]    3    3    9
[3,]    6    3    9 
[4,]    5    4    9
[5,]    1    3    8
[6,]    5    3    9
[7,]    0    0    7
[8,]    0    0    1
[9,]    0    0    9
[10,]    0    0    0
```

the max result that could be reached in column 1 is 8, in C2 is 4, and in C3 is 9. in this dataset I have ten participants that each answered all three questions. How can I normalize those values to present them neatly in a boxplot as in column 1 the max values is never reached. I appreciate your help. I also wonder if I should normalize the data at all?

Comment: If by normalize you mean find some sort of average that could be difficult. Are the numbers (1 - 10) the question numbers? / can you elaborate on how the questionnaire  works.

Comment: So if you can change C3 from 1 - 9 to 1 - 8 then you could just multiply C1 by 2 which would give you a standard resolution.

Comment: @Edward i cannot change the C3 to 1-8 as the survey is already performed. i desigend three scenarios, for each scenario a user got a different overview (made with a different method), with the help of the overview they should answer the question. each user got all three scenarios. the three columns describe the answers for the first question that is the same for all three scenarios. the result shall show which overview performs best. here in this case we see that the overview given with scenario 3 works best, as most of the users have got the max result.

Comment: I don't understand, in that case why is question 5 1 in C1 and 8 in C3? Surly they should at be down the same end of the scale at least!? Without knowing exactly what this is supposed to achieve it is going to be very difficult to give to reliable advice. I can tell you it is possible to create a common scale using division but whether you should or not depends what you are trying to show...

Comment: @Edward , participant 5 got only one point out of 8 possible for question 1 in scenario 1. in scenario 2 participant 5 got 3 points out of 4 for question 1 (in my example column 2), in scenario 3 (column 3) he got 8 points out of 9 possible. the rows show the answers of each participant. as i used different scenarios the amount of max points differs for each scenario.